# empty div with padding shows in chrome but not in ff

Tags: css, padding

I have a empty div that has background color and padding. The empty div gets populated once i login.

If i am not logged in the empty div should not show right now in ff it is not showing but in chrome the empty dive shows up as square with the background color. I cannot remove the background or the padding (as in do not want to remove it and then later add it using jq).

```
#login {
    background-color: #263171;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-table;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
<div id="login"></div>
```

any idea why its acting in this manner ?

thanks

Comment: If you're going to later add it with jQuery, why don't you just do a $("#login").hide() and then a .show() when you go to add it?  Chrome shows it because it handles `inline-table`s differently than FF.

Comment: i said i DO NOT want to later add it...basically i am using third party software so dont want to tamper too mcuh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is right. There is a bug with Firefox causing this of which is already submitted.

The bug comes from display: inline **-table**. Whatever consists of 'table'.

Try changing from display: inline-table to inline-block or inline.

Comment: Wasn't mentioning you :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. He didn't say it's a bug in FF, that's why I thought you meant me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 20px of padding which would show like a 40px x 40px dark blue square.
The border box of the element includes padding so its width and height will apear to be 40px.

Also, it should show in Firefox as well as other browsers, maybe you're not seeing it?
[Edit]: Seems to be a bug in Firefox related to inline-table.

If you want something hidden use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` depending on your use case.

Don't use empty elements for spacing, use margins or paddings for the elements you want spaced.

One more thing: it makes not sense to use `inline-table` to get it to be hidden.

Comment: No, Firefox won't show it.  FF handles inline-tables with padding differently.

Comment: Please make a Fiddle, it should be visible in any browser.

Comment: Already did.  It isn't visible on FF.  Look at my answer for the fiddle.  Its box model is 20x0

Comment: Very odd, it's probably a bug in Firefox. It's visible in IE and Opera. Padding box gets background colour, so it's normal that you see it.